# Como adicionar elementos de um arquivo em um dicionário?

Tags: python

Olá, eu estou fazendo um programa que tem que pegar todos os elementos de um arquivo (que tem varias linhas) e colocar num dicionário assim:

arquivo (1a linha) => Mercado1,biscoito,4.3,leite,3.2,suco,7.1,chocolate,6.4,detergente,3.2,cerveja,6.4,manteiga,8.7
dicionario => { Mercado1:{biscoito:4.3, leite:3.2, etc }, Mercado2:{etc} }

Então primeiro eu fiz uma função para criar os dicionários de dentro, os de cada mercado (cada linha), mas quando rodo ele só está armazenando a última linha do arquivo:

```py
def criaDicProdutos():
    arq = open('MercadosProdutos.txt','r', encoding = 'utf-8')
    dic = {}
    for linha in arq:
        lista_produtos = linha.strip().split(',')
        for i in range (1,len(lista_produtos)-1):
            teste = lista_produtos[i].isalpha()
            if teste == True:
                dic[lista_produtos[i]] = lista_produtos[i+1]
    arq.close()
    print(dic)
    return  di
```

Segue abaixo o arquivo txt que estou usando:

Qbarato,biscoito,4.3,leite,3.2,suco,7.1,chocolate,6.4,detergente,3.2,cerveja,6.4,manteiga,8.7
UltraK,biscoito,3.5,leite,3.3,suco,8.9,chocolate,6.9,detergente,4.2,cerveja,6.4,manteiga,8.7
Market,biscoito,4.5,leite,3.2,suco,7.5,chocolate,6.6,detergente,3.8,cerveja,6.5,manteiga,9.2
Preferido,biscoito,4.65,leite,3.4,suco,8.1,chocolate,8.1,detergente,3.3,cerveja,6.5,manteiga,8.9
Escolhido,biscoito,5.2,leite,3.3,suco,8.3,chocolate,7.5,detergente,3.9,cerveja,6.4,manteiga,8.6

Answer (score 0):

Basta você percorrer cada linha do seu arquivo e separar cada item da linha pela vírgula com o método de string chamado `split`. Fazendo isso, você pode criar uma chave utilizando o primeiro elemento da lista de itens, que irá guardar inicialmente um dicionário vazio para depois armazenar os produtos e os valores.

Para armazenar os produtos no sub-dicionário, podemos utilizar `for...range` para fazer com que o elemento da posição **x** seja a chave do dicionário e o elemento da posição **x + 1** seja o valor.

O problema é que se fizermos isso com um simples `range(1, len(linha))`, os elementos que deveriam ser apenas valores também se tornarão chaves. Isso porque não estamos pulando as posições percorridas e em algum momento, a chave receberia o elemento na posição do valor.

```
{"biscoito": "4.3", "4.3": "leite", "leite": "3.2", "3.2": "suco",...}
```

Então o que devemos fazer é passar para o parâmetro **step** da função `range()` o valor **2**, para que todos os elementos de posição ímpar sejam chaves e os de posição par sejam valores.

Veja abaixo o código:

```
def obter_dicionario(lines):

    dicionario = {}

    for line in lines:

        line = line.split(",")    # Separa os itens pela vírgula
        dicionario[line[0]] = {}  # Cria sub-dicionário

        for i in range(1, len(line), 2):

            chave = line[i]
            valor = line[i + 1]

            dicionario[line[0]][chave] = valor

    return dicionario


with open("<nome_do_arquivo>") as file:
    dicionario = obter_dicionario(file.readlines())
```

Comment: Que ótimo, consegui! Muito obrigada